# Spring JavaMailSenderImpl auto detect server available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I use JavaMailSenderImpl in SpringBoot website.

```
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private void sendMail(String from, String[] to, String subject, String content) 
    {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content);
        try {
            mailSender.send(message);
            PublicLogger.LOGGER_DEDUCT_GENERATE_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_IMPL.info("The email has been sent");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PublicLogger.LOGGER_DEDUCT_GENERATE_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_IMPL.error("sent email failed: {}", ex);
        }
    }
```

At night, nobody is using this website. It throws exception.
[image]

So I guess, there is some way that Spring check the SMTP server availability itself at sometimes. Do you know where to set this? Thanks.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Do you want to decrease retry time? You want to implement auto reconnect?

Comment: I think as soon as `JavaMailSenderImpl` Bean is loaded it will verify ping with host in frequent intervals

Comment: @bkbb. I want to decrease retry time.

Comment: @Deadpool. Any method inside `JavaMailSenderImpl` does this?

Comment: What about `mailSender.testConnection();`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable/disable mail health check:

application.properties

```
management.health.mail.enabled=true # Whether to enable Mail health check.
```

Comment: Is it enabled by default? Is there anyway to set the time interval?

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Boot Actuator checks if your smtp server is reachable as a part of the overall health check. And in case it's not the health check fails (503 Status: DOWN). The frequency of health checks is usually set in platform (e.g. Kubernetes) config.